# Why is Django app redirect_uri = 'web' and not my domain?

Tags: django, nginx, oauth, django-allauth

I'm setting up Oauth sign in on my django web app and am getting a redirect_uri error because my django app is using 'webhttps' instead of my domain. How can I change the redirect uri of my django app? I've got it working in my localhost but not the deployed app.

For slack authentication, expecting the passed URI to be  http://[my domain]/accounts/slack/login/callback/ but instead am getting  http://webhttps/accounts/slack/login/callback/

I think it has to do with nginx and my configuration file but I'm not too sure what to change.

Here's my mydjango.conf file:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host 'my-domain.com';

    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;

}
```

And here is my mydjango_https.conf file which sets up https for my app:

```
upstream webhttps {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webhttps/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host 'my-domain.com';
    }
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;

}
```

Comment: Please add if you are using a third-party package for it, your code that is relevant and your `SITE_ID` setting.

Comment: Hey! Yes, I'm using Django-allauth and my SITE_ID = 1. Just updated the question!

Comment: Ok, what is the value of the site with ID 1: https://localhost:8000/admin/sites/site/1/change/ ? Did you add `'django.contrib.sites',` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I think it could potentially be that I made changes to my nginx config files (above) but didn't restart Gunicorn or nginx in the server. Do you know if I would need to restart them?

Comment: Yes I've got the installed_apps. It works perfectly in localhost but not when deployed on the web

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1840#issuecomment-334923811

Comment: Yes I think it does, thanks! proxy_set_header Host worked for my local, but still not working for when it's deployed. Do you know if I change the config file to add 'proxy_set_header Host' in the server if I need to restart the server?

Comment: At least reload it, yes